# how to call a property from values in django

Tags: django, django-models

I need the value of the property, which calls through the values call so that later i will use in the union method so
used model is

```
class Bills(models.Model):

    salesPerson = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    purchasedPerson = models.ForeignKey(Members, on_delete = models.PROTECT, null=True)
    cash = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    totalAmount = models.IntegerField()
    advance = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-update', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.purchasedPerson)
    
    @property
    def balance(self):
        return 0 if self.cash == True else self.totalAmount - self.advance
```

when i call the model as

```
bills = Bills.objects.all()
```

I can call the balance property as

```
for bill in bills:
    bill.balance
```

no issue in above method but i need to use the bills in union with another model so needed fixed vales to call

i am calling the method as

```
bill_trans = Bills.objects.filter(purchasedPerson__id__contains = pk,
                                     cash = False).values('purchasedPerson',
                                         'purchasedPerson__name', 'cash',
                                         'totalAmount', 'id', 'created')
```

in place  of the 'totalamount' i need balance how can i approach this step

Answer (score 0):

you can `annotate` the balance and include it in your `values`

```
bill_trans = Bills.objects.filter(purchasedPerson__id__contains = pk,
                                     cash = False).annotate(balance=(F('totalAmount') - F('advance')).values('purchasedPerson',
                                         'purchasedPerson__name', 'cash',
                                         'balance', 'id', 'created')
```

Also, I was suggesting that the advance field should not be allowed to be null and instead give a `default` of zero

Comment: And if you also want balance to be 0 when "cash=True", you can do so with Case conditional expression - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case